# "Je dois vous rencontrer" vs. "J'ai besoin de vous rencontrer": Lequel est le plus poli et le plus formel?

Tags: politesse, formulation

> Je dois vous rencontrer.

vs.

> J'ai besoin de vous rencontrer

Lequel est le plus poli et le plus formel?

**P.S.** I have a few very important questions about an emergency topic and I need to meet the person in charge of a department at a university.

Comment: Les deux phrases n'ayant pas le même sens il faut donner plus de **contexte** pour qu'on puisse dire  quand l'une ou l'autre peut être employée.

Comment: @Laure, J'ai mis à jour ma question. Merci.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Je dois vous rencontrer.

implique une obligation morale, voire un ordre. Or d'après le contexte tu t'adresses à un supérieur auquel tu demandes un service qu'il peut, ou non, t'accorder. Il vaut donc mieux dire :

> J'ai besoin de vous rencontrer.

Et si tu veux être encore plus poli tu mettras le verbe au conditionnel :

> J'aurais besoin de vous rencontrer pour vous demander....